# Return nothing in a method where method has a definition of returning something

Tags: c#, list, methods, null, return

I have a method which returns list of objects.

```
public List<record> method(...)
```

Now inside the method, one validation comes and I don't want to return anything if its true.

Ex- `If(condition)` then I don't want to add that record.

How to proceed?

Comment: Can you show the actual body of the method? i.e. _code_

Comment: " I don't want to return anything" -> return an empty list or a null reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a return type, you suppose to return something.

Like vc74 said in comment, you can return an empty list or a null reference.

A third solution is to use a Maybe encapsulation class like this: [Maybe monad C#](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1510/maybe-monad-csharp)

With that your method will be:

```
public Maybe<List<record>> method(...)
{
    if(condition)
        return Maybe.None;

    return Maybe<List<record>>.Some;
}
```